# Visual Studio Code Logpoint syntax docs?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

Besides the current minimalistic description in the docs at https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_logpoints and blog entry at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-c-extension-july-2020-update-doxygen-comments-and-logpoints/ is it described anywhere what kind of "expressions" can be used in a logpoint?

Mainly, is there a conditional logpoint, for example if I'd like to log only certain strings (especially in C++)?

Comment: Why is documenting this 'not a thing?'

Answer (score 0):

Seems like expressions should be the same as Watch expressions with the addition of special tokens, like `$FUNCTION` and `$ADDRESS` as outlined [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-c-extension-july-2020-update-doxygen-comments-and-logpoints/)

For C++ on the Mac the above works well with cppdbg ("MIMode": "lldb"). When using an external debugger add-on, such as [vscode-lldb](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb) the special tokens might not work.

Answer (score 0):

For C++, this syntax works on Ubuntu :

```
Some random sentence : {myVariable}
```

Unlike Conditional Breakpoints where you have to write C code, Logpoints don't need to write code. And if you want to display variables' content, you can enclose them with braces.

**Important : the logpoints are displayed in the debug console of VScode, NOT in the terminal**